# Mysql auto-initialization of timestamp column when adding it to an existent table

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I want to add a column to a table to keep track of when each record was last updated. I already have some data in the table.

The SQL query I am running is this:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD COLUMN `last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL 
          DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
          ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`;
```

When adding columns of other types existent records get the default value I specify for that column. However in this case all existent records are getting assigned the value of: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`
Why is this happening if I explicitly said I wanted the default to be the current timestamp?

Comment: Maybe a version problem? I use 5.6.12 and its sets the default as specified. I have found [this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68040). Hopefully this will help you to analyze the problem.

Comment: Ah yes, it probably is. I solved it by running `update my_table set last_modified = now()`. My version is 5.5.27, so most probably it is that bug.